# Installing SBT an Mac OSX 10.6

Tags: scala, lift, sbt

I am trying to get SBT running on my Mac Operating System. 
So far, I downloaded the Jar-Launcher and installed in into the /bin folder. 
Then I created a SBT script, containing the following lines:

```
export PATH=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:$PATH 
java -Xmx512M -jar ` $0` /bin/sbt-launch-0.7.7.jar "$@"
```

When I call SBT on the Console, I receive the following series of error messages:

```
> /bin/sbt: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh": error=35, Resource temporarily unavailable
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:466)
    at jline.UnixTerminal.exec(UnixTerminal.java:297)
    at jline.UnixTerminal.exec(UnixTerminal.java:282)
    at jline.UnixTerminal.stty(UnixTerminal.java:273)
    at jline.UnixTerminal.initializeTerminal(UnixTerminal.java:77)
    at jline.Terminal.setupTerminal(Terminal.java:75)
    at jline.Terminal.getTerminal(Terminal.java:26)
    at xsbt.boot.JLine$.terminal(SimpleReader.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.JLine$.createReader(SimpleReader.scala:22)
    at xsbt.boot.SimpleReader$.<init>(SimpleReader.scala:42)
    at xsbt.boot.SimpleReader$.<clinit>(SimpleReader.scala)
    at xsbt.boot.Initialize$.create(Create.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.parsed(Launch.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.configured(Launch.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:13)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:24)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.run(Boot.scala:19)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:15)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=35, Resource temporarily unavailable
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:53)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:91)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 21 more
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Do you have homebrew installed? If not, I suggest to do so. With homebrew it's as easy as typing 'brew install sbt'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a stray `$0` there (which is expanded to the name of the current process `sh`). Try

```
java -Xmx512M -jar /bin/sbt-launch-0.7.7.jar "$@"
```

instead. That should get you up and running. The usual way is to call `sbt` like so:

```
java -Xmx512M -jar `dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

supposed you have the shell script `sbt` in the same folder as `sbt-launch.jar` because that is where `dirname $0` points at.